# How can I get SPI SCK line to idle low without wasting current with a pulldown resistor?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, c, spi, c++

I am using the STM32L475 MCU and am using SPI to communicate with an SD card.

When I configure the SPI SCK GPIO pin, I configure it as Alternate Function SPI in PushPull mode. I set the ClockPolarity to be idle low, which would make me think that the SCK line would remain low when inactive, but this is not the case. Instead, the SCK line idles high until SPI communications are started. This means that if I do a SPI write and subsequent read, an extra clock pulse is triggered, throwing off my communications.

The only way I found to be able to fix this is to further configure the GPIO pin to have a pull-down resistor, but this seems to me like it will be wasteful in terms of current draw. Configuring the pin as open-drain doesn't do the trick either, since I need to add a pull-up in that case anyway. Finally, I have tried writing to the GPIO pin's output register for the SCK pin and setting it to be low, but this does not change anything.

It seems to me like my only option is to place a pull-down resistor on a push-pull pin and constantly waste current in order to have the SCK line stay low. I was wondering if this was the normal solution that people used for SPI communications? I can't imagine that it is.

Comment: Sounds like that should not happen. Please post schematics and code to find the issue.

Comment: It sounds like you're not configuring things the way you think you are, or are not setting up the MCU peripheral to think it "owns" the bus.

Comment: Why exactly does the polarity of the clock matter when you aren't sending anything?

Comment: @Lundin *Some* SPI parts require the SCK line to idle in a known state (sometimes high, sometimes low depending on the part) - that is why we have the clock polarity control.

Comment: @PeterSmith We have clock polarity to tell if the slave should read data on rising edge or falling edge during data transmission. But it wouldn't surprise me if there's weird implementations that require a certain idle state.